# Why were there scratches on Cole's back and through his clothes?

Tags: the-sixth-sense

In one scene in *The Sixth Sense*, Lynn, Cole's mom, notices two holes in her son's clothes (around 53 minutes in), with corresponding large scratches on his back. Ghosts are all shown to be injured or sick like they were when they died, and

> there is still a hole in Malcolm's shirt from the gunshot.

In the movie, and from what I've found online, there isn't much about why Cole can see dead people. **What’s going on with the wounds?**

[image: Holes in his red sweater] [image: Scratches on his back]

Comment: I've made the images smaller with a click through link to the original image just because they were dominating the page and didn't need to be so big. If you don't like the change though feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 4):

Lynn finds that Cole's clothing is torn, not necessarily that there's a distinct "entry/exit wound" kind of hole. In the incident with Cole and the closet, we see that the dead can physically grab people. Likely, the torn clothes were the result of the ghosts grabbing and scratching at Cole and his clothing (whether due to their general trauma making them violent, or their desperation upon finally finding someone they can speak to). This is likely also the source of the scratches on Vincent.

You can see another likely case of such tears when Cole is using the bathroom before encountering the kitchen ghost. I can vouch from my experience as a child that this is exactly the sort of rip you get from clothing that's grabbed and yanked, although my experience was from younger siblings, not ghosts.

[image: image of Cole with rips in his undershirt]

And no, it's never explained why Cole (or Vincent before him) can perceive ghosts.

Comment: Incidentally, they came to the same answer at https://www.quora.com/How-did-Cole-get-his-scratches-in-the-Sixth-Sense-Were-they-self-inflicted-or-from-the-ghosts